# How to set ariaLabel value in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a typescript react app, and I am trying to set the ariaLabel value dynamically, ESLint is complaining `Property 'ariaLabel' does not exist on type 'HTMLButtonElement'`.

I tried multiple types but none have the ariaLabel property, and I don't want to use `<any>`

```
const ref = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
const buttonRef = ref.current.querySelector<HTMLButtonElement>(`[aria-label="${buttonAriaLabel}"]`);
buttonRef.ariaLabel = eventLabel; // here is the error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aria-label is an attribute so you can change your code for

```
buttonRef.setAttribute("aria-label", eventLabel);
```